# How to compare two columns in multiple files in linux with awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have this code

```
[motaro@Cyrax ]$ awk '{print $1}' awk1.txt awk2.txt
line1a
line2a
file1a
file2a
```

It shows the ccolumns from the both files

How can i find `$1(of file 1)` and `$1(of file2)` , separately

Comment: Your question is really quite ambiguous. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14250405/edit) your question to include some example input (i.e. what are the contents of `awk1.txt` and what are the contents of `awk2.txt`?) and please include some expected output. Also, how do you define the word 'compare'? The simplest way to print column one of file1 and column one of file2, separately, would be to do: `awk 'FNR==NR { print $1; next } { print $1 }' file1 file2`. But this is not what you want to do. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: @STEVE , that `FNR = NR` what i was looking for. i wanted to just know how to diff between columns of diff files. but how can i do if i have three files

Comment: I've added an answer, but please see the link. There's info there on how to handle multiple files using a loop up. However, if you find yourself opening a large number of file-handles, there may be a better approach to solving your problem. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above, for three or more files, set the conditionals like:

```
FILENAME == ARGV[1]
```

For example:

```
awk 'FILENAME == ARGV[1] { print $1 } FILENAME == ARGV[2] { print $1 } FILENAME == ARGV[3] { print $1 }' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Alternatively, if you have a glob of files:

Change the conditionals to:

```
FILENAME == "file1.txt"
```

For example:

```
awk 'FILENAME == "file1.txt" { print $1 } FILENAME == "file2.txt" { print $1 } FILENAME == "file3.txt" { print $1 }' *.txt
```

---

You may also want to read more about the variables [ARGC and ARGV](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/ARGC-and-ARGV.html). Please let me know if anything requires more explanation. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0;next} {print a[FNR],$0}' file_1 file_2
```

found [here](http://objectmix.com/awk/762171-how-merge-two-files-row-row.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you need.
Probably you need predefined variable :`FILENAME`

```
awk '{print $1,FILENAME}' awk1.txt awk2.txt
```

This above command will output:

```
line1a awk1.txt 
line2a awk1.txt 
file1a awk2.txt 
file2a awk2.txt
```